DuckDB: Aggregate JSON Lists (Unique)
Is there a way to flatten a list of nested values from a json column to a list of distinct values:
ie:
from: {"unique_values":[["105125"],["105125"],["105125","0]]}
to: {"unique_values": ["105125","0"]


Is order important? Does your JSON data contain other keys? Can you provide a minimal example?

An initial attempt using:

json_transform() to turn the json into repr into an actual list
flatten()
list_distinct() to remove duplicates
json_merge_patch() to add result back into the JSON

tbl = duckdb.sql("""
from (values
   ('{"id":1,"values":[["1"],["1"],["1","0"]]}'),
   ('{"id":2,"values":[["2"],["3"],["1","3"]]}')
)
select col0::json as j
""")

duckdb.sql("""
from tbl
select json_merge_patch(j, 
   {
      "values": 
         json_transform(j.values, '"VARCHAR[][]"')
           .flatten()
           .list_distinct()
    }::json
) as j
"""
)

┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│                j                │
│              json               │
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│ {"values":["0","1"],"id":1}     │
│ {"values":["1","3","2"],"id":2} │
└─────────────────────────────────┘

However, some potential issues:

list_distinct() cannot retain the original value order.
json_merge_patch() loses the original key order.

Retaining original order
If dealing with other keys and order is important, it seems one needs to unnest the full json object.
I'm using json_group_structure() here to "dynamically" extract the "schema".
schema = duckdb.sql("""
from tbl select json_group_structure(j)
""").fetchone()[0]

'{"id":"UBIGINT","values":[["VARCHAR"]]}'

It is somewhat wordy as we manually unnest, flatten, distinct along with using 2 separate row_number() expressions for both row and value order.
duckdb.sql(f"""
with 
data as (
   from tbl 
   select 
      row_number() over () row_number,
      unnest(json_transform(j, '{schema}')) 
),
distinct_data as (
   from (
      from data
      select * replace unnest(values.flatten()) as values
   )
   select distinct on (row_number, values) 
      *, 
      row_number() over () as list_idx
),
distinct_lists as (
   from distinct_data
   select 
      first(columns(* exclude (values, list_idx))),
      list(values order by list_idx) as values
   group by id
   order by row_number
),
result as (
   from distinct_lists select * exclude row_number
)
from result 
select result::json as j
""")

┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│                j                │
│              json               │
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│ {"id":1,"values":["1","0"]}     │
│ {"id":2,"values":["2","3","1"]} │
└─────────────────────────────────┘

I would hope there is a way to simplify this.
